# How to fix web component to get scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, scrollbar

So I'm trying to make a web component, *my-thing*, that can be placed anywhere in html.  But I'm having problems with getting scrollbars to work.

Given this sample ([codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMmQXm?editors=1000)), and without changing the stuff marked "can't change", how do I get the scrollbars to appear?

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        .my-thing {
            white-space: pre;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px red solid;
            /*width:100%;*/
        }
    </style>

    <br />
    <div style="display:flex"> <!-- can't change -->
        <div>                  <!-- can't change -->
            <div class="my-thing">
        This has NO scrollbars!!
        This is a loooooooong and boring piece of text that really doesn't deserve to be read at all.
        This is another loooooooong and boring piece of text that really doesn't deserve to be read at all.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="my-thing">
        This auto scrolls correctly.
        This is a loooooooong and boring piece of text that really doesn't deserve to be read at all.
        This is another loooooooong and boring piece of text that really doesn't deserve to be read at all.
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**:  Also you can't manually change the width of my-thing. Ideally we want "width:100%".

Comment: add `min-width: 0` to the wrapper inside the flexbox container: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRNoZz?editors=1000

Comment: @kukkuz Not really. Ideally, I'd like the "width:100%"

Comment: add `flex: 1` to it too?

Comment: see the updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRNoZz?editors=1000

Comment: Sorry @kukkuz, we can't change that line as the comments indicate

Comment: if you can't change the *flex container* or *flex child* I can only think of *positioning*: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qweXbZ?editors=1000

Comment: Interesting... but absolute positioning doesn't work for many reasons.

Comment: I understand you can't change the wrappers - but here is another case that works if the *wrapping flexbox* has `flex-direction: column` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXgMJb?editors=1000 :)

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the width and height of my-thing class to any value.
set width of the component to make horizontal scrollbar appear, and height to make vertical scrollbar appear

```
 .my-thing { white-space: pre; overflow: auto; border: 1px red solid; width: 100px; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sherif, but I typically I want "width:100%"